# how to define 2 habtm Association in one model in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

i have a model that have 2 habtm association.

my models are: 'Course', 'Teacher' and 'Student.

course hasAndBelongsToMany Teacher and hasAndBelongsToMany Student.

when i coding like this:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = 'Student';
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = 'Teacher';
```

Or:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Student' => array(
        'className' =>  'Student',
        'joinTable' =>  'courses_students',
        'foreignKey'=>  'course_id',
        'associationForeignKey' =>  'student_id'
    ),
    'Teacher' => array(
        'className' =>  'Teacher',
        'joinTable' =>  'courses_teachers',
        'foreignKey'=>  'course_id',
        'associationForeignKey' =>  'teacher_id'
    )
);
```

i see internal error

how can i code this?

Thanks

Comment: 2nd one looks fine, what internal error are you seeing?

Comment: just says: 'Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.'

Comment: Check your app error log /app/tmp/logs/error.log

Comment: 2013-02-15 16:18:50 Error: Fatal Error (64): Cannot redeclare class Course in [C:\xampp\htdocs\school\app\Model\Teacher.php, line 4]
2013-02-15 16:18:50 Error: [InternalErrorException] Internal Server Error

Comment: The errors says it all! you probably have a copy-and-paste-error. You declare the class wrong in your Teacher.php (should be Teacher not Course).

Comment: @mark please re-write your comment as an answer so that this question can be marked 'answered' by OP

Answer (score 0):

"Cannot redeclare class Course"
says it all: you probably have a copy-and-paste-error.

You declare the class wrong in your Teacher.php (should be Teacher not Course).